# How to import external dependencies with Bazel?

Tags: java, bazel, dataflow

I want to import `Google Cloud Dataflow SDK For Java All 2.0.0`.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud.dataflow/google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all/2.0.0

But this artifact includes `SdkDependencies` class file only.

How can I import All dependencies of `Dataflow SDK`?

I tried `generate_workspace` according to the procedure. (https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/generate-workspace.html)

It is hard to add Dataflow SDK dependencies manually.

```
deps = [
    "@org_apache_beam_beam_sdks_java_core//jar",
    "@org_apache_beam_beam_runners_google_cloud_dataflow_java//jar",
    "@org_apache_beam_beam_sdks_java_io_google_cloud_platform//jar",
    "@com_fasterxml_jackson_core_jackson_annotations//jar",
    "@com_fasterxml_jackson_core_jackson_databind//jar",
    "@com_fasterxml_jackson_core_jackson_core//jar",
    ...
]
```

What is the usual way to import external dependencies?

Comment: Can you add a link to pastebin or github gist of the generate workspace outputs? Generate workspace actually allows you to specify only the leaf but I want to double check and explain to you via the output

Comment: Does using maven_jar [1] help? https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/workspace.html#maven_jar